# How to pass parameter to function inside react component..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass a parameter to the common function when my dom is loaded. I can't use useEfect in my case. So I create a function for that. I need to check some parameters' true and if it is true I return true or I return false.

```
export function validateUser(data) {
  if (data==='order/view'){
    return true
  }
    return false
  
}
export default validateUser();




return (
    <div hidden={()=>{validateUser('order/view')}}> Som Data </div>
)
```

If div returns 'order/view' I need to show my div and if it's not, I need to hide my div in my react site. But My method can't return the parameters that I send it to.
If anyone can help me with that question, It really helps.

Comment: Why can't you use `useEffect` hook? What are you trying to conditionally render? Also, `validateUser` could use some Boolean Zen applied to it, simply return the result of the boolean expression, i.e. `return data === 'order/view'`. Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are wanting to call `validateUser` to conditionally set the `hidden` prop being passed to the div. Instead of passing an anonymous callback just directly invoke `validateUser` and pass the return value as the `hidden` prop value.

```
export function validateUser(data) {
  return data === 'order/view';
}
export default validateUser();
```

...

```
return (
  <div hidden={validateUser('order/view')}>Some Data</div>
)
```

or if you really are conditionally rendering some content

```
return validateUser('order/view') ? (
  <div>Some Data</div>
) : null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const validateUser = data => data === 'order/view'



export const ChildComponent = ({data}) => {



return (
    <div hidden={()=>{validateUser(data)}}> Som Data </div>
)

}

const ParentComponent = (props) => {

  return <>
    <ChildComponent data={props.data} />
  </>
}
```